# What is the best way to detect a primitive stored in a Java Object?

Tags: java

I need to convert to Integer a value Stored inside a Java Object, what would be the best way to detect what kind of value the object contains?

For example, when an Double is stored in the object i do this:

```
Double myval = 0.0;
Object myobj = myval;  
if (myobj instanceof Double) {Double dd = (Double) myobj; converted = dd.intValue();}
```

I dont know if this is efficient, or the best way. Since the object can contain any type of value (Double, Integer, int, float) what would be the best way to detect primitive values?

Thanks.

Edit:
  After reading the answers, i realized an object cannot contain primitives, so, the question was wrong. Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: Some more background information would be *very* helpful.

Comment: I think this resumes the question, but, sure. What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 3):

All Object number types are subclasses of Number:

```
if (myobj instanceof Number) {converted = ((Number)myobj).intValue();}
```

Comment: If this works, it might be the best i have learned this week, does it works with all data types? (testing right now).

Comment: all boxed primitives except booleans and chars.

Answer (score 2):

If it contains all different kinds of numbers, you could use:

```
if (myobj instanceof Number) {
    converted = ((Number) myobj).doubleValue();
}
```

This will handle `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Float`, and `Double`, along with most—but not all—`Long` values (values larger than ±2<sup>52</sup> will be subject to rounding). Using `doubleValue()` is best so as to avoid the truncation that `intValue()` or `longValue()` might introduce.

An `Object` can't store primitive values so you don't need to check for those. They will have already been [boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) into their corresponding reference types: `int` to `Integer`, `float` to `Float`, etc.

Comment: Does it work with primitives? (after edit: Nice! then this does the task nicely, thanks!)